# Prove that if a,b & k are natural numbers such that $k^{\frac{a}{b}}$ is rational, then $k^{\frac{a}{b}}$ is a natural number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proposed solution: we know that  $k^{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{m}{n}$is rational,where m,n $\in$ Z. Assume w.l.o.g. that (m,n)=1. Then 
$nk^{\frac{b}{a}}=m$
$n^{a}k^{b}=m^{a}$
Then we write $n^a,k^b,m^a$ in their canonical form, because every prime factor of $n^a$ appears in $m^a$ and they are raised to the same power, so that $n^{a}\mid m^{a}$, thus $n\mid m$. Because (m,n)=1, so n=1. Thus $k^{\frac{a}{b}}=m$ is a natural number.

Is this correct? Is there any improvement that can be made? Thanks!

Comment: This is totally correct. It's a special case of a more general result that says: every rational algebraic integer is in fact an integer (an algebraic integer is a root $\in \mathbb{C}$ of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients). $k^{a/b}$ is a root of the monic polynomial $X^b - k^a$, which certainly has integer coefficients.

Comment: Actually, there's a small typo. You flipped $a$ and $b$ near the beginning, and then flipped them back near the end.

Comment: Your second line should read $n k^\frac{a}{b} = m$ instead of $n k^\frac{b}{a} = m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should say a bit more precisely how you conclude $\,n\mid m\,$ using prime factorizations. Here is one way: $ $ if $\,|n|>1\,$ then $\,n\,$ has a prime factor $\,p,\,$ so $\,p\mid n^b\,\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid m^b = n^b k^a,\,$ thus $\,p\mid m^b\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid m,\,$ by $\,p\,$ prime. But $\,p\mid m,n\,$ contradicts $\,(m,n)=1.\,$ Thus $\,|n| = 1.$

Simpler, a rational root of the *monic* $\,x^b-k^a\in\Bbb Z[x],\,$ is integral, by the [Rational Root Test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Comment: Thanks! I will add this part to my homework.